# How can I serve a webpack'ed (Vue) app through Django without recompiling for every change?

Tags: django, vue.js

I set up a Django project and want to develop a Vue frontend to go along with it. To set up the Vue app, I used `vue init webpack myproject-frontend`. Developing both separately is pretty straight-forward, using `python manage.py runserver` and `npm run dev`, respectively.

Putting the app inside one page of my Django project is easy as well; *if* I build the Vue app using `npm run build` first. Obviously, that has the downside of being slow, plus I have to take care of the hash-containing file names (which can be automated, of course).

Regarding `npm run dev`, I'm not too satisfied with only being able to see just the Vue app in the browser. I can still communicate with my API (taking care of CORS), but that's not how the website is going to look in the end. I plan to have multiple Vue components on the same page, and different components on different pages at one point, and that's not reflected by `dev`.

How can I achieve the quickness of not having to rebuild constantly, while retaining the fidelity of not omitting the Django part of the application?

---

I tried to look at what is served by `dev`, but I'm too new to Webpack and the used tooling to deduce an approach out of that. FWIW, this is what I looked at:

- looking at `http://localhost:8080/`, I see this:

  ```
  <div id="app"></div>
  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
  ```
- `/app.js` itself seems to be the result of webpack'ing some bootstrapping, library and application code. But that file is nowhere on my file system, so I can't serve it from Django...

Comment: It took me way too long to find a solution that is obvious in hindsight, so I'm posting this for the rest of the world. I'm still interested if there's a CORS-less solution!

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's possible to serve the `dev` version of the app through the Django server somehow (i.e. on port 8000 instead of 8080 in case of the defaults), I don't know.

However, that doesn't mean it can't be integrated into the Django web site. Everything that's necessary is visible in the source of `localhost:8080/`:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
```

And this part of HTML can be served by Django, achieving almost the same thing as putting the `dist` files in Django's static dir - the difference being the port and thus CORS:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/app.js"></script>
```